# Derivation of optical theorem in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm working on the optical theorem (page 234). However, there seems to be some contradiction in my derivation
[image]

According to Eq.(7.54), we have
\begin{align}
 i \delta \mathcal{M} &=-2 \pi i \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \int_{m}^{\infty} d E_{\mathbf{q}} E_{\mathbf{q}}|\mathbf{q}| \frac{1}{2 E_{\mathbf{q}}} \frac{1}{k^{0}\left(k^{0}-2 E_{\mathbf{q}}\right)}\\ \delta \mathcal{M}&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \int_{m}^{\infty} d E_{\mathbf{q}}  \frac{|\mathbf{q}|}{2} \frac{1}{k^{0}\left(k^{0}-2 E_{\mathbf{q}}\right)}\\ \text{Im}\delta \mathcal{M}&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \text{Im}\int_{m}^{\infty} d E_{\mathbf{q}}  \frac{|\mathbf{q}|}{2} \frac{1}{k^{0}\left(k^{0}-2 E_{\mathbf{q}}\right)}
\end{align}
Apply 
$$\frac{1}{k^{0}-2 E_{\mathbf{q}} \pm i \epsilon}=P \frac{1}{k^{0}-2 E_{\mathbf{q}}} \mp i \pi \delta\left(k^{0}-2 E_{\mathbf{q}}\right)$$
we have
\begin{align}
\text{Im}\delta \mathcal{M}&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \frac{|\mathbf{q}|}{2} \frac{1}{k^{0}}\left(-\pi\right)\left|_{k^0=2E_{\mathbf{q}}}\right.
\end{align}
Consider $k^2=(k^0)^2$ and $E_{\mathbf{q}}^2-|\mathbf{q}|^2=m^2$
\begin{align}
\text{Im}\delta \mathcal{M}&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \frac{\sqrt{E_{\mathbf{q}}^2-m^2}}{2} \frac{1}{k^{0}}\left(-\pi\right)\left|_{k^0=2E_{\mathbf{q}}}\right.\\&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \sqrt{\frac{E_{\mathbf{q}}^2-m^2}{(k^0)^2}}\frac{1}{2}\left(-\pi\right)\left|_{k^0=2E_{\mathbf{q}}}\right.\\&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \sqrt{\frac{k^2-4m^2}{4k^2}}\frac{1}{2}\left(-\pi\right)\\&=-2 \pi  \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \frac{4 \pi}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}\frac{1}{4}\left(-\pi\right)\\&= \frac{\lambda^{2}}{16\pi}\sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}\\&=\frac{\lambda^2p_{cm}}{8\pi E_{cm}}
\end{align}
However, according to peskin Eq.(7.50) and Eq.(4.100)
$$\operatorname{Im} \mathcal{M}\left(k_{1}, k_{2} \rightarrow k_{1}, k_{2}\right)=2 E_{\mathrm{cm}} p_{\mathrm{cm}} \sigma_{\mathrm{tot}}\left(k_{1}, k_{2} \rightarrow \text { anything }\right)$$
$$\sigma_{\text {total }}=\frac{\lambda^{2}}{32 \pi E_{\mathrm{cm}}^{2}}$$
The $\text{Im}\delta \mathcal{M}$ should be $\frac{\lambda^2p_{cm}}{16\pi E_{cm}}$. According to the calculation result of peskin problem 7.1, I also obtain$$\text{Im}\delta \mathcal{M}=\frac{\lambda^{2}}{32\pi}\sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}=\frac{\lambda^2p_{cm}}{16\pi E_{cm}}$$
I'm sure I'm wrong about $\text{Im}\delta \mathcal{M}$, but where is it?

Comment: Did you remember the factor of $1/2$ from the Jacobian of the delta function? $\int dE_{\mathbf{q}} F(E_{\mathbf{q}}) \delta(k^0 - 2 E_{\mathbf{q}}) = \frac{1}{2} F(E_{\mathbf{q}})\big|_{k^0 = 2 E_{\mathbf{q}}}$

Comment: Thank you very much!  I made a stupid mistake...

Comment: Hi, can I ask a small question? is $p_{cm}^2=\frac{E_{cm}^2}{4}-m^2$ in your post? And this is the same $p_{cm}$ in eq.(7.50)? I am really troubled why the definition of $p_{cm}$ looks like this, could you please explain more?